# list2cmdline Needs raw text

Tags: python, subprocess

Whilst using `list2cmdline`, I need to pass a certain part of a string as a quoted string every time. But using list2cmdline doesn't give me this option. The problem is that the last part of the string comes from a user input, so I can't just change it to always be valid.

## Broken Example

For example, when I have

`list2cmdline(['node', '/path/to/mylatexbuilder', 'x^2\\sab+2x'])`

The output is:

`node /path/to/mylatexbuilder x^2\sab+2x`

Which will fail with the builder I am using.

## Working Example

Now if I make a very subtle change, I'm litteraly just going to add a space inside the string, so for example:

`list2cmdline(['node', '/path/to/mylatexbuilder', 'x^ 2\sab+2x'])`

Now the output is what it should be:

`'node /path/to/mylatexbuilder "x^ 2\\sab+2x"'`

This is safely used by POpen later on.

## My Question

How can I force python to always quote the last input?

Comment: I should add that the first example fails because the \sab is escaped

Comment: are you using windows? I suppose so.

Comment: note that `list2cmdline` only predicts what the command line is going to be. But it's not like that that it is built.

Comment: Nope, I'm on a mac. But the backspaces here are just raw text that need to be preserved.

Comment: [mcve] please. I think you're mixing up `str` with `repr` (printing vs getting the value through the interpreter). I don't see a change (except for the space & the quotes)

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood something here, If I just call `print(list2cmdline(['node', '/path/to/mylatexbuilder', 'x^2\\sab+2x']))`, my output is different to what I would get if I call `print(list2cmdline(['node', '/path/to/mylatexbuilder', 'x^2 \\sab+2x']))`, which is causing havoc later on

Comment: Since I'm using this as an invocation later on, not having the quotes causes another issue when passing to my shell. Without the quotes, things that shouldn't be escaped are escaped.